# Dynamic Form Builder with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, dynamic, builder

I am planning to build a dynamic form for different form layout with

http://bootsnipp.com/forms?version=3

I wanna do this with CodeIgniter PHP framework. Frontend section of builder like this link.
Backend section some problem

1. I wanna save in database a created form layout built with this builder. This is completed
2. When i want to use this saved form layout a lot of problem occurs.
   2.1 How can i control form element in codeigniter like form validation because all of form element name dynamically created
   2.2 How can i store in database this dynamic value ? I can't design my database for saving dynamic value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a formbuilder years ago and used 3 tables:

**tblForms**

Hold's the meta informations of the forms, like name, etc.

**tblFormDetails**

Hold's the form element info's like type, name, rules. Each element in one row. tblFormDetails references to tblForms.

**tblFormData**

Hold's the values. Each value in one row. It references to tblFormDetails and has a requestId for grouping the values per form.

Comment: Thanks good advice for db table design. How did you manage to form validation ?