# Dynamic Form Builder In Android

Tags: android-activity, formbuilder, jasonette

Can any body know how to implement the dynamic form builder base on API response in Android ?

I don't know how to build it in android activity and what's required api response.

I refer the bellow link for implement it in android

[Dynamic Form Builder with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973451/dynamic-form-builder-with-codeigniter)

[database schema for a dynamic formbuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516231/database-schema-for-a-dynamic-formbuilder)

but can't understand exactly what was required

So, please help me if there any one know dynamic form builder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long terms, I got a some good library **[JASONETTE-Android](https://github.com/Jasonette/JASONETTE-Android)** and  **[Avocarrot/json2view](https://github.com/Avocarrot/json2view)** which basically work on JSON object to implement the dynamically form of Android means you can convert your JSON object to Android View.